# woocommerce reduce space between image and details

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

My product page has a large amount of whitespace in the middle, between the image and the product details. How do i reduce this space please?? I'm not sure which bit of code is controlling this.

Please see my page here - https://flowersforeveryone.feedmybeta.com/product/precious-pink-tulips/

[image: remove whitespace]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `.woocommerce-page div.product div.summary {width: 50%;}`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure what code controls the container, but the code I changed to make the image a bit smaller was -  
.woocommerce div.product div.images.woocommerce-product-gallery {
  width: 40%; 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz4kC.png

Remove the width or you can make `width: 60%`

Comment: Oh brilliant.. thanks! the only issue is now some of the elements in product details (the horizonal lines and add to cart button) are now super wide. What would I change to keep these the original width? I actually want to space everything in the center of the page

Comment: Then you can add margin right to the right block. But as your site is having full width then margin right will not give a better look.

Comment: cool thanks. i fixed the problem by just reducing the width of the add to cart button and lines